# making a where clause optional by checking a variable value in a sql statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select, where-clause

Is there an option in sql where i can make a where clause in a select statement optional based on a variable value.
For Ex:- If i have a query like this.

```
Declare
@selection int=1
select name,age,department from employee where age > 25
```

i want to make the where clause to be applied only if @selection=1 and not apply if @selection is something else. Can i do this without if condition?

Comment: Suggested reading: [Dynamic Search Conditions in T-SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can express that logic using an OR

```
select name,age,department 
from employee 
where @selection <> 1 or age > 25
```

If @selection <> 1 then the first part of the condition ensures that all the rows are returned, but if it's exactly 1 then you will check "age > 25"

I would add an isnull function to ensure that when @selection contains a null value it still returns all the rows.

```
select name,age,department 
from employee 
where isnull(@selection, 0) <> 1 or age > 25
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use boolean logic in the `where` clause:

```
declare @selection int = 1
select name, age, department 
from employee 
where (@selection = 1 and age > 25) or @selection <> 1
```

Comment: If @selection contains a null value then your query won't return any row.

Answer (score 1):

If your query is pretty short you could just duplicate the query and have one with the where statement and one without, and execute them based on the value of the variable.  Like this:

```
Declare @selection int=1
IF @selection = 1
BEGIN
 select name,age,department from employee where age > 25
END
ELSE
BEGIN
 select name,age,department from employee
END
```

There are probably more elegant solutions, but this will get the job done if you're in a hurry and don't mind the duplicate selects.

Comment: I had an ugly long select query so was thinking better then an if condition possible.. the boolean logic was smooth